# store a boolean for when the column header that reverses sorting order is clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I have a datagrid and by default, you can click on the header of each column to reverse the sorting order. Is there a way to store a boolean to indicate that the sorting order was switched?

This is an image of when the header has been clicked and the down arrow indicates that the order has switched.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect when the user changes the sort, listen to the [headerRelease](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#event:headerRelease) event of the DataGrid (if using mx DataGrid) or [sortChange](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGrid.html#event:sortChange) event (if using spark DataGrid).